# miniconda fails to install anaconda (installs anaconda custom with no packages)

Tags: anaconda

I'm using the following script to install (reinstall) the latest anaconda on a machine in a silent mode. It has been working fine for a long time, successfully installing anaconda. However, it broke recently, and now instead of installing all the anaconda packages, it just ends up installing " anaconda: custom-py36hbbc8b67_0 ". The script is below, and its output is after that

```
cd ~
rm -r ~/miniconda3 ~/miniconda ~/anaconda ~/anaconda3
set -e
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -f
echo 'PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
conda install anaconda -y
```

Output of "conda install anaconda -y":

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/imakaev/miniconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    anaconda: custom-py36hbbc8b67_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:    4.3.31-py36_0         --> 4.4.3-py36_0

anaconda-custo 100% |###################################################################| Time: 0:00:00  15.63 MB/s
conda-4.4.3-py 100% |###################################################################| Time: 0:00:00  48.26 MB/s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [conda packages with version name of 'custom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782008/conda-packages-with-version-name-of-custom)

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
conda update anaconda
```

to get a versioned Anaconda.

See [conda packages with version name of 'custom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782008/conda-packages-with-version-name-of-custom) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Anaconda just stays as "custom" on a fresh install of miniconda. Updating keeps it as "custom". Is it possible to force anaconda to a non-custom version?