# install all of anaconda from miniconda

Tags: docker, anaconda, miniconda

What the title says: if I have miniconda installed, what's the easiest way to install all the packages that would have been installed, had I started by installing anaconda instead?

---

For context, I'm doing this with docker. I'm starting with https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/Dockerfile, which installs miniconda. Then I'm doing `RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes anaconda`. But the output of that is only:

`Step 3/7 : RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install --yes anaconda # anaconda
 ---> Running in 2b1e512efd38
Solving environment: ...working... done
anaconda-custom      |    6 KB | ########## | 100%
certifi-2018.8.24    |  140 KB | ########## | 100%
conda-4.5.11         |  1.0 MB | ########## | 100%
openssl-1.0.2p       |  3.5 MB | ########## | 100%`

...and at the end of the day I cannot, for instance, do `import numpy`. I thought that installing anaconda would install numpy (and all the other stuff)?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955185/miniconda-fails-to-install-anaconda-installs-anaconda-custom-with-no-packages

Answer (score 4):

The packages in Anaconda are defined by the `anaconda` meta-package. So

```
conda install anaconda
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. If it does right, I should be able to import numpy, right? But I can't. Edited question...

Comment: Are you sure you're running `/opt/conda/bin/python`? What is the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`?

Comment: Step 2/8 : RUN python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
 ---> Running in e4060eb4d59c
/opt/conda/bin/python

Comment: And what about `/opt/conda/bin/conda list`? Does that show NumPy installed?

Comment: (Although, you have completely changed the question now, from what it was originally...)

Comment: (well, sort of - I mean, it should still be applicable?) - nope, numpy not installed. So when it downloaded anaconda-custom, do I then have to do anything with that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not an answer to why it was happening in the first place, but as a workaround:

```
conda install anaconda=5.2.0
```