# Is it safe to run conda updates that leads to custom package?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, conda

To be on the safe side, I was advised to keep to

```
$ conda update anaconda
```

However, some tutorials on internet recommends

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda update --all
```

The above two commands lead to the installation of custom packages. Will it cause anaconda to be unstable? Is it safer to simply keep to `conda update anaconda`?

Custom packages refer to packages with names that contain the word "custom". They do not belong to the standard anaconda package.
[conda packages with version name of 'custom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782008/conda-packages-with-version-name-of-custom)

I am using Anaconda Python version 3.

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom' packages?

Comment: Custom packages refer to packages with names that contain the word "custom". They do not belong to the standard anaconda package. conda packages with version name of 'custom'
I edited the question to add more details.

Comment: Your question has already been answered by Kale here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893068/1005215

Comment: The -custom version of the package is only for the anaconda meta package. Nothing else. You don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the correct command to update all anaconda python packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811146/which-is-the-correct-command-to-update-all-anaconda-python-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Open "Command or Conda Prompt" and run:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

It's a good idea to run both commands twice (one after the other) to be sure that all the basic files are updated.

This should put you back on the latest 'releases', which contains packages that are selected by the people at Continuum to work well together.

If you want the last version of each package run (this can lead to an **unstable environment**):

```
conda update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing some projects and they depend on the previous version of some packages then running `$ conda update --all` will be disastrous. It may break some of the code from your project.

Running `$ conda update anaconda` will be a safe option because along with anaconda it will update all of the required dependencies to the required version.